# Case em mysql - exibir certa quantidade

Tags: mysql

Estou com uma baita dúvida em um sql:

O website é divido por 3 categorias, cada categoria tem destaque, só que o cliente pediu que quer limitar a quantidade de produto destaque por categoria.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim: tenho 100 registros dentro desta categoria, 50 deles são destaques e 50 não, eu preciso fazer um sql que destes 50 destaques, sejam exibidos os últimos 10 cadastrados (limite de 10) e o restante dos 50 registros que não são destaques também sejam exibidos. Estive pensando em case, mas não tenho noção de como dar Limit dentro do case.
Alguém já teve que fazer algo parecido ou tem alguma dica para passar??

Segue SQL que já tenho:

```
SELECT id, id_user, lead_size, titulo_size_interno, lead_size_interno, 
   imagem_interno, titulo_size, id_categoria, tipo_interno, destaque_interno, 
   titulo, slug, lead, imagem, tipo 
FROM tb_post 
WHERE ativo = 1 AND data_post <= NOW() AND ultima = 0 
 AND id_categoria IN(5)  ORDER BY ordem_interno DESC, id DESC
```

Estive pensando em algo assim (nunca utilizei a sintax do case, é um exemplo):

```
SELECT id, id_user, lead_size, titulo_size_interno, lead_size_interno, 
  imagem_interno, titulo_size, id_categoria, tipo_interno, destaque_interno, 
  titulo, slug, lead, imagem, tipo 
FROM tb_post 
WHERE ativo = 1 AND data_post <= NOW() AND ultima = 0 
  AND id_categoria IN(5)  
ORDER BY ordem_interno DESC, id DESC case(destaque_interno = 1 limit 10)
```

Comment: A exibição será de 10 destaques + 50 não destaques, ou 10 destaques + 90 registros não selecionados como os 10 destaques?

Comment: Boa pergunta, a exibição deverá ser: tenho 100 registros, destes 100, 20 são destaques, só que marquei que quero exibir só 5 destaques destes 20, então os outros 15 que sobrariam deverão ser exibidos abaixo com os não destaque. Deu para entender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segue resposta, acabei tendo que fazer um union :)

```
(SELECT p.id, 
        p.titulo, 
        p.id_categoria,
        c.quantidade_destaque,
        p.destaque_interno,
        c.nome
        FROM tb_post p 
        JOIN tb_post_categoria c ON p.id_categoria = c.id
        WHERE p.ativo = 1 
        AND p.data_post <= NOW() 
        AND p.ultima = 0 
        AND c.id =3
        AND p.destaque_interno = 1
        ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 2)
        UNION
(SELECT p.id, 
        p.titulo, 
        p.id_categoria,
        c.quantidade_destaque,
        p.destaque_interno,
        c.nome
        FROM tb_post p 
        JOIN tb_post_categoria c ON p.id_categoria = c.id
        WHERE p.ativo = 1 
        AND p.data_post <= NOW() 
        AND p.ultima = 0 
        AND c.id = 3
        ORDER BY p.id DESC)
```